# TouchJSON on iOS: dictionaryWithJSONString unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, static-libraries, touchjson

I have a static library with TouchJSON in it and I am trying to use `dictionaryWithJSONString:error:` (within the static library) but I keep getting the runtime exception shown in the title.

I have included the `NSDictionary` category header file and the implementation file of the extension is definitely in the compiled resources list of the static library.

What else could be the problem?

Comment: Please include the code (including where the object you call the method on is created) where the exception is raised, and the actual exception message - in the title you haven't said what class is actually receiving the message. It is probably a memory management issue, but it is impossible to tell without the information above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add -ObjC to `Other Linker Flags` in the build settings of your application target.